# Create Deeply Nested JSON with Recursion

Tags: java, json, recursion, simplejson

This JSON is the output that I am expecting,

```
    [{
    "text": "a",
    "nodes": [{
        "text": "aa",
        "nodes": [{
            "text": "aa1"
        }, {
            "text": "aa2",
            "nodes": [{
                    "text": "aaa1"
                },
                {
                    "text": "aaa2",
                    "nodes": [{
                        "text": "aaaa21"
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "text": "aaa3"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "text": "b",
    "nodes": [{
            "text": "bb1"
        },
        {
            "text": "bb2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "text": "c",
    "nodes": [{
        "text": "cc"
    }]
},
{
    "text": "d",
    "nodes": [{
        "text": "dd1",
        "nodes": [{
                "text": "ddd1"
            },
            {
                "text": "ddd2"
            },
            {
                "text": "ddd3",
                "nodes": [{
                    "text": "ddd31",
                    "nodes": [{
                        "text": "ddd32"
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

So to in short from the below table structure I want to generate a JSON tree like above, Please someone share me a java code/Algorithm for this..

A simple recursion method would help me, Or Is there any standard library to do this

[image]

Comment: Why don't you post your code that fails and we can try to help you fix it?

Comment: Please share your code so one could help you identify problems with your approach and guide you rather than just asking for a solution.

Comment: Added the code, Thank you @Nick

Comment: @digidude Added my code which makes a recursive query and builds the desired JSON from the resultset.

Comment: Hi @vigneshwar.java.developer I still haven't investigate why you are getting the Stack Overflow error, but there is one obvious flaw with your code i.e. the return type of method being JSONObject where as you expect to store multiple nodes. Your sample JSON hints that it should be JSONArray instead.

Comment: Adding the code doesn't anyone to figure out the problem, So now I edited the question, please share me some sample code or algorithm to do this., Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that your recursive function executes the SQL query each time it is called and so never gets beyond the first result row. Hence the stack overflow. Re-structure your code so that the query is executed just once at the beginning. I haven't got time to set up a table to try this out, but intuitively, you need to move the function to start just before the 'while' loop.

Comment: I have another method calling this method (recursiveRead), don't want to put all code here and I purposely making a recursive call to get child nodes (aa),  grandchild node (aa1, aa2), child of grandchild node (aaa1) and so on...